# Drill down for array of data in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I have an array `[["event",2],["status",30]]` as data for series. I want to include **drill down** for each data. How can i do this?

```
        series: [{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Device Status',
                    data:  <?php echo json_encode($rows)?> ,
                    drilldown: 'animals'

                }],
                 drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }
                ] }
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for this>> http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.2.4/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/?

Comment: now <?php echo json_encode($rows)?> is returning this [{"name":"event","y":2,"drilldown":"animal"},{"name":"status","y":30,"drilldown":"animal"}]

Comment: Please create a fiddle for this, with exact data what you are receiving from the server.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nhkkyfxw/1/ i have created fiddle for this.

Comment: working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/nhkkyfxw/2/

Comment: Thank you @ karman. I missed to include the plugin for drilldown